# Go vs. Scala for realtime webapps

Tags: scala, go

I'm writing a webapp that uses websockets for updating vehicle positions on a google map and for exchanging messages with drivers in realtime. I've been playing around with Node.js as well as Tornado, but I've come to the conclusion that I'd prefer static typing for this project after all.

Two excellent choices seem to be Scala and Go, but I'm having a hard time deciding between those two. I've been mostly been programming in C/C++/C#/Python and have very little Java experience.

So how do those two compare? What would you learn next? I know this is subjective, but I'm kind of looking for some battle stories here. Also, what about the ecosystem? From what I can tell, Scala inherits Java's ecosystem, but what about Go?

Comment: You probably mean something else than "realtime"; the term "realtime" has a special meaning in computing (i.e. it is software that has hard guarantees that actions are done within a certain time frame).

Comment: Well, the term realtime web is commonly used when it comes to server push. But I'm not talking about realtime systems, you're right.

Comment: I too have been programming, mostly, in the languages you've listed and Go was really quite easy to pick and and go. You may never end up picking one over the other if you're looking for the better of the two, so just pick one and go with it. (I used the word `go` a lot, so you know what I've chosen =) )

Answer (score 4):

The down side of Go - immature, with very little real world experience.

The down side of Scala - you must be familiar with the Java eco system in order to utilize scala well. You probably can't write everything in Scala. Also, some might find the learning curve for Scala higher.

Both supports websockets (Scala through Lift for instance, and Go in the standard library).

I believe that you'll be more comfortable with Go, since it's more similar to Python than Scala.